# Page redirected too many times ASP.NET

Tags: authentication, redirect, active-directory

Dear StackOverflow community,

I am still new with ASP.NET and playing have been playing around and I've encountered an error to authenticate my login where it shows up an error like "Page redirected too many times" and it happen something that are keep looping and I can't figure it out after 2 days.

I've implemented my login using header.acsx so it can be a global authentication to all page.

Here is the code of head.vb:

```
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session(GetSessionKey("UserName"))) Then
    Dim userName As String = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Split("\")(1)
    SessionInitialiser(userName)
End If
Response.Redirect("~/EventRegistration.aspx")
```

Page_Load function:

```
Dim adserv As New ActiveDirectory()
        Dim userDetails As WebServiceUserPrincipal = adserv.Getuser(userName)
        Dim userGroups As String() = adserv.GetUserGroups(userName)

        Dim _dt As New DataTable
        _dt.Columns.Add("Group")

        For Each item As String In userGroups
            Dim _row As DataRow = _dt.NewRow()
            _row("Group") = item
            _dt.Rows.Add(_row)
        Next

        Session(GetSessionKey("FullName")) = userDetails.DisplayName
        Session(GetSessionKey("Groups")) = _dt
        Session(GetSessionKey("UserName")) = userName
        Session(GetSessionKey("Switch")) = "OK"


        Dim filter_auditGroup As String = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("FILTER_GROUP")
        Dim _adt As New DataTable
        _adt.Columns.Add("Group")
        For Each item As String In userGroups
            If (item = filter_auditGroup) Then
                Dim _row As DataRow = _adt.NewRow()
                _row("Group") = item
                _adt.Rows.Add(_row)
            End If
        Next
        'If _adt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        '    Session(GetSessionKey("AuditGroups")) = _adt
        'End If
    End Sub
```

Check Access Function

```
  If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim arr As Array = Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Split("/")
        Dim page As String = arr(arr.Length - 1).ToString().Split(".")(0) '-- Ballot.aspx, remove .aspx and get Ballot only

        Dim signOut As New List(Of String)
        signOut.Add("SwitchUser")
        signOut.Add("SignOut")

        If (Not signOut.Contains(page, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) Then
            If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session(GetSessionKey("UserName")))) Then
                Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx")
            Else
                Dim group As DataTable = Session(GetSessionKey("Groups"))
                'Dim auditGroup As DataTable = Session(GetSessionKey("AuditGroups"))

                Dim adminPage As New List(Of String)
                adminPage.Add("BallotProcess")
                adminPage.Add("CodeTablePage")
                adminPage.Add("MaintainBallotItem")
                adminPage.Add("MaintainCodeItem")
                adminPage.Add("MaintainItemDetail")

                If (adminPage.Contains(page, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) And Not CheckAdmin(group)) Then
                    Response.Redirect("~/EventRegistration.aspx")
                End If

                'If (page.Equals("AuditPage", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) And Not CheckAudit(group)) Then
                '    Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx")
                'End If
                End If
        End If
    End If
```

Check Admin Function

```
Private Function CheckAdmin(ByVal group As DataTable) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    If Not IsNothing(group) Then
        For i = 0 To group.Rows.Count - 1
            If group.Rows(i)(0) = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("FILTER_GROUP") Then
                CheckAdmin = True
                Session(GetSessionKey("EventAdmin")) = 1
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my answer through countless of debug and all I need to fix this code is just move the Response.Redirect("~/EventRegistration.aspx") into the If Else statement above. This is because when the if else statement execute to get the identity, after its if else statement the value will be Nothing, then it redirect to the page while the page will try to get the identity and it execute again the if else countless of times..

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session(GetSessionKey("UserName"))) Then
Dim userName As String = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Split("\")(1)
SessionInitialiser(userName)
```

Response.Redirect("~/EventRegistration.aspx")
End If